# Authorization/API key text box not appearing on Swagger Page

Tags: swagger-ui, java-11, dropwizard, swagger-2.0, bearer-token

I have upgraded the dropwizard swagger version in my code. Now after upgrading the same I am not able to see the API_KEY textbox on swagger page.

I have changed the maven dependency From

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.federecio</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Swagger Page Before

[Swagger Page UI Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CZON.png)

To

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smoketurner</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.12-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Swagger Page After Upgrading the dropwizard version

[Swagger UI Page after upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NIrc.jpg)

I want the Swagger page should has some Authorize/ API token text box so I can provide the oauth token on the page.